# OCR for scanning printed receipts.

Tags: windows-phone-7, ocr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can OCR software reliably read values from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173439/can-ocr-software-reliably-read-values-from-a-table)

This is a follow up from this post - [Can OCR software reliably read values from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173439/can-ocr-software-reliably-read-values-from-a-table?rq=1)

My question is - Is it possible for OCR to scan **receipts** with printed item names and price values? I am currently developing an app for Windows Phone 7 using Project Hawaii's OCR service. If it is, How do I do it?