# tesseract reading values from a table

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

My question follows this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173439/can-ocr-software-reliably-read-values-from-a-table) about extracting data from a table in an image using OCR.

I'm using `tesseract` to convert a table image to text. This works well except that the format of the table is not preserved. One solution is to replace the columns with some letters `tesseract` would recognize and fool it into taking the table just as some text.

Here is an example of a table without columns [image]

I use the following code to draw the columns of "QQ"

```
im=Image.open("file.png")
draw  = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font=ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerifBold.ttf",12)
by = font.getsize("S")[1]
col = [240,480]
px = []

for y in range(0,im.size[1],by):
    for x in col:
        draw.text((x,y),"QQ",font=font,fill=0)

im.save("res-file.png")
im.show()
```

which give me the following image
[image]

The problem is that tesseract does even recognize the QQ.
I write the QQ columns in a blank page as well and tesseract didn't recognize it.

Is there a way to convert this table in png format to text using tesseract? Is there something that escaped me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue was with the vertical spacing of QQ. by adding some vertical spacing and resizing the image I got acceptable results

```
im=Image.open("file.png")
draw  = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font=ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerifBold.ttf",12)
by = font.getsize("S")[1]
col = [240,480]
px = []

for y in range(0,im.size[1],by+5):
    for x in col:
        draw.text((x,y),"QQ",font=font,fill=0)
im=im.resize((im.size[0]*2,im.size[1]*2))
im.save("res-file.png")
im.show()
```

Here is the text obtained after `tesseract res-file.png outputfile`

8888 
8888

Shop §Date open§Town 
Mike §2007-Nov-09§sourisvi||e 
Abbibas §2009-Jan-05§magic city 
Iuma $2009-Jan-05§vani||a 
Beboot §2009-Mar-31§at|antis 
bascics $2008-Jun-27§o|d york